# Why does my function stop returning the correct value?

Tags: python

I have a proof that `((2^(2*i))-1)/3` is always odd, and in particular it seems like the 1's digit alternates between 1 and 5 as `i` gets bigger. I wrote the following python function to do the math.

```
def A():
    for i in range(513):
       x = int((2**(2*i)-1)/3)
       print(x)
```

Once `i` gets bigger than 28, the 1's digit stops alternating between 1 and 5 and starts alternating between 4 and 6. The correct numbers aren't even, of course, so I'm thinking the computer must be messing up the calculation somehow. Why should this be happening?

Comment: Because it only "seems like the 1's digit alternates between 1 and 5 as i gets bigger"?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that when I calculate ((2^(2*29))-1)/3 on this website, it returns a number with a 1 in the 1's digit. I tested some other values that seem to confirm this conjecture. https://defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm

Comment: Assuming you are using Python 3, dividing by 3 produces a floating point value whose value you are truncating. At some point, the numbers are getting to big for floating point values to represent accurately.

Comment: Thank you @chepner!

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote? I am new to this stack community.

Comment: {1/3 (2^(2 x) - 1), x = 32} — Using WolframAlpha, the first digit is 6.

Comment: the downvote is probably because searching for `python division wrong` on SO will give you more than a hundred explanations of what's happening.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar I am worried about the 1's digit, which seems to be 5 on wolphram alpha. In other words, numbers in this form always seem to equal 1 or 5 mod 10. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B1%2F3+(2%5E(2+x)+-+1),+x+%3D+32%7D

Comment: @hop Thank you hop!

Comment: @hop To be fair, the issue here is with precision in the integer part of the result, not just the loss of the fractional part. Most questions here ask why `2/3` is 0, not 0.6666666666667.

Comment: @chepner: I didn't say it's fair, I just stated what was probably the reason. I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, the division by 3, as pointed out in the comments by [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner), produces a floating point imprecision.

Replacing `int( ... / 3)` by `... // 3` will fix it:

```
x = (2**(2*i)-1) // 3
```

The `//` operator is the integer division.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, the `/` operator *always* produces a floating point value:

```
>>> 1/3
0.3333333333333333
```

Unlike an `int`, which can represent any integer accurately, floating point values have a fixed precision; you only have so many significant digits available. Say you only had 3 significant digits available; 10,000/3 would give you 3330 instead of 3333.333333333333. As a result, your answer isn't exactly correct, even before you drop any fractional part using the `int` function.

[Right Leg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44074320/1126841) gives you the correct workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Let's split the calculation at a critical point, and add an integer division:

```
for i in range(25,35):
    temp = (2**(2*i)-1)/3
    itemp = (2**(2*i)-1)//3
    print()
    print ("{0:16d}".format(itemp))
    print ("{0:16.10f}".format(temp))
    x = int(temp)
    print (x)
```

This allows you to note the loss once you hit the limits of floating-point accuracy.  Output:

```
375299968947541
375299968947541.0000000000
375299968947541

1501199875790165
1501199875790165.0000000000
1501199875790165

6004799503160661
6004799503160661.0000000000
6004799503160661

24019198012642645
24019198012642644.0000000000
24019198012642644

96076792050570581
96076792050570576.0000000000
96076792050570576

384307168202282325
384307168202282304.0000000000
384307168202282304

1537228672809129301
1537228672809129216.0000000000
1537228672809129216

6148914691236517205
6148914691236516864.0000000000
6148914691236516864

24595658764946068821
24595658764946067456.0000000000
24595658764946067456

98382635059784275285
98382635059784269824.0000000000
98382635059784269824
```